# Is this a possible structural isomer for Butene(C4H8)

Tags: molecular-structure, structural-formula

Today in school, my teacher was explaining the different types of alkenes. Examples included ethene, propene, and butene.  She also showed us their structural formulas.
I tried to draw butene's formula and came up with this:

[image: http://imgur.com/dw4nIkz]

Is it correct?

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you had any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Correct; and the more common example is 1-butene: H2C=CH-CH2-CH3

Comment: And there are also the *cis*- and *trans*- forms of 2-butene. And if one just went by the molecular formula, there's cyclobutane and methylcyclopropane as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the formula you drew is an example of [isobutylene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isobutylene).  Isobutylene has the "official" IUPAC name of 2-methylpropene, and is an important industrial chemical.  Because it:

1. has a formula of $\ce{C4H8}$, and thus contains four carbon atoms;
2. contains a carbon-carbon double bond;
3. and doesn't contain any other functional groups

... it is indeed an isomer of butene (sometimes known as butylene).  You got this one right!$%edit$